# Touch not working on Unity on my Android device

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity remote 5 and i am trying to make a simple image gallery, if you press on the right of the screen it moves forward and if you press on the left it moves bakcwards...

The problem is that not a single touch is being registered, even using "Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);" gives me no input whatsoever and i dont know what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Diapositiva{

public string nombre;
public string descripcion;
public Sprite imagen;

public Diapositiva(string _nombre,string _descripcion, string _imagen){

    nombre = _nombre;
    descripcion = _descripcion;
    imagen = Resources.Load<Sprite>(_imagen);

}


}

public class Controlador : MonoBehaviour {

public Text nombre;
public Text descripcion;
public Image dibujo;
public int indice = 0;

public List<Diapositiva> Diapositivas = new List<Diapositiva>();

public void LoadDiapositivas(){
    nombre.text= Diapositivas[indice].nombre;
    descripcion.text= Diapositivas[indice].descripcion;
    dibujo.sprite = Diapositivas[indice].imagen;
}

void Left()
{

    if (indice <= 0) indice = Diapositivas.Count - 1;

    else indice--;
    LoadDiapositivas();

}

void Right()
{

    if (indice >= Diapositivas.Count - 1) indice = 0;

    else indice++;
    LoadDiapositivas();

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    Diapositivas.Add(new Diapositiva("Darinka", "Mi amorcito", "Sprites/Darinka"));
    Diapositivas.Add(new Diapositiva("Hitler", "Heroe de Alemania", "Sprites/Hitler"));
    Diapositivas.Add(new Diapositiva("Nikola Tesla", "Científico mas inteligente del mundo", "Sprites/Tesla"));
    Diapositivas.Add(new Diapositiva("Guts", "Personaje principal de Berserk", "Sprites/Guts"));

    LoadDiapositivas();
    Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);

    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {

        if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            float middleScreen = Screen.width / 2;

            if(touch.position.x < middleScreen && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {


                Left();

            }

            else if (touch.position.x > middleScreen && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {

                Right();
            }
        }

    }



}

}
```

Comment: I have noticed that if i remove this line: if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {} it works... but i added that to identify what platform is running on... i don't get why adding that "if" breaks everything.

Comment: Yes, the problem is causing by this line. But the real problem is because you are using Unity Remote 5. So the `Application.platform` actually returns your Unity Editor. Further explanation and solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53642563/4877424).

Answer (score 0):

Using Unity remote 5 dosen't means you are using mobile device. 
It just a second screen with touch .
All the conditions would be the same as your desktop.
Even the screen resolution is the same as your current Game view window .
So RuntimePlatform value should be Windows/OSX.