# Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Like I said in this other question that no one has answered:

[Touch not working on Unity on my Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638992/touch-not-working-on-unity-on-my-android-device)

I discovered that the problem of my app not working was this lines:

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {

}
```

If i remove that condition the app works like it should but the moment i add it back it just doensn't work.

Comment: Are you running this code on Android devices as an individual app? I ask this because you mentioned that you run on Unity Remote 5 in previous post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow you posts, I did an experiment.

First, I try run below code on Remote 5 and run it as an individual app respectively.

```
void Update () {
    Debug.LogFormat ("Application.platform: {0}", Application.platform.ToString ());
}
```

On Remote 5 app, the console prints:

```
Application.platform: OSXEditor
```

On individual app, the console prints:

```
Application.platform: Android
```

Apparently, the `Application.platform` is not working as you expected with Unity Remote 5, so your code doesn't work when you put them inside the if statement. Actually, your code would work perfectly without using Remote 5.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Don't use Unity Remote 5 to test your app. Though it's a pretty handy way to test your game, sometimes it's not working as you expected when you deploy your app to the real device.
2. Use [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). I recommend you to use this for develop your game on different platforms. As the [RuntimePlatform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.html) document suggests:

> The difference between using RuntimePlatform and Platform dependent Compilation is that using RuntimePlatform is evaluated at runtime while Platform dependent Compilation is evaluated at compile time. So if you can use platform dependent compilation, don't hesitate to use it. In most cases, you can get the same functionality using both, and using the defines will produce smaller and faster code, as you don't need to check at runtime. There are some cases where RuntimePlatform is needed at runtime.

Here is an example to run your code on only Android platform with platform dependent flag.

```
    void Update () {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        // Run your Android only code here.
#endif
    }
```

Comment: So basically I need to do separate codes for different platforms?, if i compiled the code the app would run normally if each time i wanted to test it i made an apk?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If the feature only works on mobile platform,  I think building the apk and tested it the only way. But if the feature is not platform specific, you can still test it with Unity Editor.

Comment: I tested my code as an apk that i built, and it works but now there are 2 problems, first one of the buttons i made to go back to a previous scene does not show on screen and it looks like everything is a bit zoomed, the second thing that happened is that "Application.Quit();" is not working on a button that I made,

Comment: I believe those are not relative to this problem. And if you want, you can ask in other posts.

Comment: Ok i will do it.